# Manual grinder that fits inside the Aeropress

Tags: grinder, aeropress

What is a good manual grinder that will fit inside of the Aeropress for travel purposes?

I'm looking for something as good as my [Commandante grinder](http://www.comandantegrinder.com/). I'm happy with the Commandante, but if I'm ever upgrading the grinder in the future I'd like something that will fit inside the Aeropress.

Comment: Inside as in “set in top, so that all grinds fall directly into the Aeropress”? Interesting question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Aergrind by Knock is made for just this purpose. No personal experience with this grinder, but from what I've seen it has good reviews: https://prima-coffee.com/equipment/knock/aergrind

Comment: Please elaborate on your answer, as it's currently written it may be seen and flagged as spam.

Comment: About to say exactly this, I've got this grinder fit's nicely in the Aeropress (sticks out at the end a little) and grinds well. 
Some good recommendations for settings here: https://thebarn.de/pages/aergrind-manual-1